# How to Parse an Array of Elements in Gutenberg Block

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I have a custom Gutenberg block which is attempting to take an array of strings and save them as `<li>` elements. Everything works as expected and displays correctly to the end user, but I'm getting validation errors after reloading the editor.

Here is the validation error:

```
Expected:

<div class="wp-block-ggcn-blocks-query-string-content"><span class="data-drop" newtab=""></span><ul class="tabs"><li class="tab"><li class="tab">Tab1</li></li><li class="tab"><li class="tab">Tab2</li></li></ul><p class="custom-content"></p></div>

Actual:

<div class="wp-block-ggcn-blocks-query-string-content"><span class="data-drop" newtab=""></span><ul class="tabs"><li class="tab">Tab1</li><li class="tab">Tab2</li></ul><p class="custom-content"></p></div>
```

Here is my save function:

```
save({attributes, className}) {
  const { tabs, newTab, content } = attributes;

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <span className="data-drop" newtab={newTab}></span>
      <ul className="tabs">
      {tabs.map(tab => {
            return <li className="tab">{tab}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>          
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is how I'm parsing the attributes:

```
attributes: {
  tabs: { 
    type: 'array',
    source: 'children',
    selector: 'ul.tabs',
    default: []
  }
}
```

Obviously I'm parsing out the entire HTML list elements, when I only want the text. But when I change the selector to be `ul.tabs > li`, I get only the text for a single element, and lists of more than 1 item fail validation.

Can someone help me understand how to get an array of text values?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround, sparked by @tmdesigned's answer, which I'm going to post as an answer. It is not pretty and I don't think it can be the "canonical" answer, but hopefully it helps us get there.

So first, I kept the attributes using a `source: children`:

```
tabs: { 
  type: 'array',
  source: 'children',
  selector: 'ul.tabs',
  default: []
}
```

This meant that on initial save, I was dealing with an array of strings, but on subsequent loads in the editor, I was dealing with an array of objects, since my source type of children was pulling in the `<li>` elements themselves in the list, instead of the text values of the elements.

My solution was to map over these elements and convert them back into an array of strings. This had to be done in both the `edit` function and the `save` function.

```
const tabValues = tabs.map(tab => {
  if (typeof(tab) === 'object')
    return tab.props.children[0];

  return tab;
});
```

Then later in the output, I was able to output like this:

```
{tabValues.map(tab => <li key={tab} className="tab">{tab}</li>)}
```

If anyone has a solution that relies exclusively on the data parse and doesn't require this workaround, I will mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the attribute's source to children, it gives you DOM elements, i.e. including the wrapping HTML and not just the inner text.

So the behavior you're seeing, which you probably already know, is the HTML elements getting nested inside of themselves. You're wrapping the contents in `<li>`, which gets wrapped in `<li>`, which could get wrapped in `<li>` again, and so on.

That part I'm pretty sure about. The solution below is my *understanding* of how to do it, but having not yet done this type of attribute selector, *I haven't fully tested this*. That being said, I think what you are looking for is closer to:

```
attributes: {
  tabs: { 
    type: 'array',
    source: 'query',
    selector: 'ul.tabs',
    default: [],
    query: {
      val: {
        type: 'string',
        selector: 'li',
        source: 'text',
    },
  }
}
```

So we're creating an array of objects with one property, which comes from each children's text. Then in your save function, you have to specifically pull that new `val` property we just specified as coming from the inner text of the `li` selector:

```
save({attributes, className}) {
  const { tabs, newTab, content } = attributes;

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <span className="data-drop" newtab={newTab}></span>
      <ul className="tabs">
      {tabs.map(tab => {
            return <li className="tab">{tab.val}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>          
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the `query` source is a great idea. Implementing this still left two problems:

1. I was still only getting a single `<li>` element back.
2. On the initial save, the value was coming through as a `string` type, but on loading after parsing the block, the value came in as an `object` type.

I think this is probably the correct solution, but maybe I still need to tweak something? However, it did spark some ideas which helped me get a workaround in place.

Comment: By using the above described method you will get array of `<li>` elements via `props.attributes.tabs.val`. For updating that set of array you will have to use redux kind of approach on those particular attributes.